# How to display the custom taxonomies of a Wordpress categories page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to add custom taxonomies to my Categories page (renamed to Authors) and whilst I can expose non-taxonomic custom fields cannot do the same for any taxonomic relationships this category might possess in even a basic way.

I've tried using the guide to exposing taxonomies on the ACF website looping out the relevant entries in a foreach loop to no avail.

On Posts I've used 'the_terms' and pulled out various custom taxonomies by drawing on the post id but I haven't been able to tweak this for use on a Category page.

This is what I use on Posts and works fine:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'century', '', ' , ' ); ?>
```

Because a Category isn't a Post 'the_terms' doesn't work in this context. This is what I use on the Category to show its custom taxonomies in a basic way:

```
<?php 
$term = get_queried_object();

$locations = get_field('location', $term);
$century = get_field('century', $term);
$tradition = get_field('tradition', $term);
$characteristics = get_field('characteristics', $term);
$related = get_field('related', $term);

foreach($locations as $location){
echo $location;
} 
foreach($century as $centur){
echo $centur;
} 
foreach($tradition as $traditio){
echo $traditio;
} 
foreach($characteristics as $characteristic){
echo $characteristic;
}
foreach($related as $relate){
echo $relate;
}
?>
```

The only results that are returned are: $location and $century. Century isn't a taxonomic relationship and location does return the ID - all my taxonomic relationships return the ID because changing it to display the Term Object causes the page to crash when the above code is used. This seems a seperate but probably related issue.

What I want to do is ideally loop the aforementioned taxonomies in the following format:

```
<?php 

$category = get_queried_object();
$terms = get_field('location', $category);

if( $terms ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is this code is currently not returning anything.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the results from var_dump($category)

`object(WP_Term)#9457 (17) { ["term_id"]=> int(196) ["name"]=> string(7) "Jan Hus" ["slug"]=> string(7) "jan-hus" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(196) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(11) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["term_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["cat_ID"]=> int(196) ["category_count"]=> int(11) ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> string(7) "Jan Hus" ["category_nicename"]=> string(7) "jan-hus" ["category_parent"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: ```var_dump($category)``` and post your returned value please.

Comment: Term Object causes the page to crash when the above code is used is because you can't echo an object. I would suggest as above var_dump() and print_r() on your variables to see what you are getting if anything. Also do you have debug on in your functions.php?

Comment: @DanielVickers see update

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below - you have to use a combination in the second parameter of `get_field` - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

```
    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
    $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  

    $image = get_field('field_5d04699ba10da', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
```

I'm getting an image field using the field key rather than name, but the important part to the problem is the second parameter of `get_field`

Comment: Thanks - how do you identify the field key in this setting?

Comment: Sorry I got that sorted now - I'm not getting a return on the field unfortunately. When I var_dump $queried_object I'm not actually seeing any of my custom taxonomies listed as options. I'm not sure why that is.